# Webrtc Firefox Android Safari iOS stream error

Tags: android, ios, firefox, safari, webrtc

I am having trouble seeing and hearing the other end's video when connecting iOS Safari with Firefox Android. When a remotestream is added I add the stream to the video's srcObject. 
Safari seems to be unable to see or hear Firefox stream, on the other hand, Firefox cannot see Safari's stream but it van hear it.

The rest of the browsers combinations (Chrome Android/Desktop, Safari Desktop/iOS and Firefox Desktop) work. Does anyone know what may be the problem?

I do not know what part of my code could help to see the problem or if it is a browser's bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on Firefox, after version 63 it is possible to connect to Safari